# how to play video after 10 second in html video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Video On background of a page code is given below:

```
 <video id="kon">
     <source  data-src="comp/vid/gyu.webm?>" media="(min-width: 640px)" src="<?=SITE_MEDIA?>video/gyu.webm?>">      
    </video>
```

> i want to hold the video for 10 sec after completing the video and
>   start it again.Its not getting pause how can i make it to pause it fo 10 sec and start it aain

Comment: keep the default autoplay false..& then set a jquery timer

Comment: can you please update the code ??

Comment: do you want replay again in 10 seconds or just once

Comment: no i want to replay again after 10 sec ..

Comment: but but...why 10 seconds...what if the video  length if more than 10 secs...it will then start the video before it is finished...

Comment: why not replay after the video is finished...just write loop="true" and then you wont have to write the javascript manipulation as well :)

Comment: can u please update the code rohitas@@

Comment: i have updated my answer...let me know if it worked as per requirement

Comment: where ???? updated code??

Comment: see my answers below...cick the "Run code snippet"

Comment: okk ...so you want the video to start after 10 seconds from the page download & repeate the whole video after the video is finshied...am i correct now ?

Comment: i want to stop it for 10 sec at the end of the video and after 10 sec start it again

Comment: what happen @Rohitas Behera ??

Comment: @sweta: isnt that already provided in my code?

Comment: Milind@ your code is not working in my case i dnno why.. 
 
i want to stop it for 10 sec at the end of the video and after 10 sec start it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
vid.playbackRate = 0.4;

vid.onended = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    vid.play(); //will play after 10 seconds when video is ended
  }, 10000);
};
vid.play(); // will play on load.

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can use setTimeout in `onended` event to play video after 10 seconds:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("kon");
vid.playbackRate = 0.4;

vid.onended = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    vid.play(); //will play after 10 seconds when video is ended
  }, 10000);
};
vid.play(); // will play on load.
```

Comment: @sweta: check in demo above.

Comment: Its working after removing the loop from the video tag thanx milind@@